# Rsync photos from internal to external hard drive

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rsync, sudo

I have ~18gb worth of photos/videos on my internal that I'm trying to move to my external via Rsync.  I initially tried:

```
sudo rsync -avh --progress --delete /Non-system files/Photo.photoslibrary/ 
/#2/Text_photos/
```

But no dice, "No such file" error. I thought that maybe .photoslibrary had to be in a folder so I moved it to "photos" folder in Non-system files and subsequently tried:

```
sudo rsync -avh --progress --delete /Non-system files/photos/
Photo.photoslibrary/ /#2/Text_photos/
```

I'm still getting the same error of:

```
rsync: link_stat "/Non-system" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Users/jcb_carrillo/files/photos/Photos" failed: No such file 
or directory (2)
```

So two things I've noticed but don't know why it's reacting the way it is. 
1. It's not reading the space in my partition "Non-system files" it only reads "Non-system".

And 2. Once the first error of "No such file or directory" happens it for some reason moves to "/Users/jcb_carrillo/files/photos/Photos" which is in an entirely other partition that as you can see in my command, was never specified to go there.

I think there's something wrong with my syntax. Any idea?

Comment: You have to quote paths containing spaces: `'/Non-system files/...'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to escape the blank space for the directory name "Non-system file"

```
sudo rsync -avh --progress --delete /Non-system\ files/Photo.photoslibrary/ 
/#2/Text_photos/
```